# Adding a java class file in an another java class file

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, database-connection

I am doing a jsp project in which, I have a dbconn.java page in which database connection to MySQL database is created.

I want to call it in an another java page for getting the database connection.

I dont know how to include the page dbconn.java into my page. Please help.

I know its a simple question for you all, but I could not find the answer.

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
package com.act;

public class dbconn {


     public String execute() throws Exception 
      {
          Connection con=null;
          Statement stmt1=null;
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabasename", "root", "password");     
      }
}
```

This is my dbconn.java page. Is this correct?

Comment: After making the calling to dbconn page whether I have to do any extra code for getting the variables in that page in my opage? means whether I can directly use the connection variable?

Comment: Can you show an example where you try to use dbconn.java?

Comment: @cctan,
In my page i tried this but its showing errors Connection con = new dbconn().getCon(); String x=null; Statement stmt1=null; stmt1 = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs1=(ResultSet) stmt1.executeQuery("select * from masterdetails;"); while(rs1.next()) { x=(String)rs1.getString("name"); System.out.println(x); } return "success";

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `Connection` object from this utility class.
I rewrite your class with name `ConnectionManager` like this :

```
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectionManager{
    private Connection con = null;
    public Connection getCon(){
        try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabasename","root", "password");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Now in your other classes, call this class like this whenever you need a db-connection:

```
Connection con = new ConnectionManager().getCon();
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("YOUR SQL QUERY");
```

Comment: In my page i tried this but its showing errors



     Connection con = new dbconn().getCon();
         String x=null;
     Statement stmt1=null;
     stmt1 = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs1=(ResultSet) stmt1.executeQuery("select * from masterdetails;");
     while(rs1.next())
     {
     x=(String)rs1.getString("name");
     System.out.println(x);
     }
     
     return "success";

Comment: Unhandled exception type SQLException-
itis showed for statement line

Comment: this java class files are inside a package com.act, whether I have to mention it?

Comment: you need to wrap the database transaction with `try-catch` block. Your code should be :  `try {Connection con = new dbconn().getCon(); String x=null; Statement stmt1=null; stmt1 = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs1=(ResultSet) stmt1.executeQuery("select * from masterdetails;"); while(rs1.next()) { x=(String)rs1.getString("name"); System.out.println(x); } return "success"; } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); return "input";}`

Comment: no need to mention package, if you have `import`-ed the `dbconn` class

Comment: Whether I have to give import statement on the top of the page?